# How can I move right side of icon image?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

[I want to move the right side of the icon. How can I do that? Does anyone help me, please
Thanks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKmu8.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think, What you mention seems to be 'actions'

Did you see this?

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
   AppBar(
     actions: [
       const Icon(
        Icons.smart_button,
        size: 18,
       )
     ],
   )
```